# Link to current page html

Tags: html, wordpress, anchor

Have been searching some topics but don't think I have found the exact answer I was looking for hence I try here.  In my Wordpress website I have a hardcoded button on around 150 pages on each top of a page. I would like to link to an angor text /#anchor halfway of each of  this pages.

Now I don't want to enter every specific URL manually. Is there a HTML trick where you refer to the current URL, something in the order of: .com/currentpage/#anchor?

Thanks in advance for any help or tips.

Comment: so you wants to be in same page& want to scoll to 'angor' component?

Comment: If it helps in your search, the word is actually "anchor".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a link on current page without add a page url.

For hash

```
<a href="#currentPageLink">Link</a>
```

For QueryString

```
<a href="?currentpagelink=true">Link</a>
```